# How can I handle unmarshaled data to original data?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am implementing some application with camel.

My scenario is like blow.

1) Collect files in input directory.

2) Unmarshal the file with specific data format (fixedLengthFormat).

3) If the file is abnormal during unmarshal, some exception is generated.

4) If the exception occurs, camel moves original file to exception directory.

I found exception like below.

```
 org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: C:\home\WRK\PRC\WLNE\IPTVKR\KRLPPM10\FATAL\SLPNPM_FGIDRO01_ID0006_T20190312050500.DAT
at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:354) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:305) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:169) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:80) ~[camel-core-2.23.1.jar:2.23.1]
    ....
```

This is an error caused by bad parsing of body.
So, I added  tag with String type before  tag.
I did this and there was no error.
But, moved file has data format to unmarshal, not original data.

How should I handle some code in order to get original data?

- Data Format for unmarshal (KRFixedFormat.java)

  ```
  @FixedLengthRecord(length=3005, header=KRHeader.class, footer=KRTailer.class)
  public class KRFixedFormat implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @DataField(pos=1, length=1,trim=true)
  private String sType;

  @DataField(pos=2, length=7, trim=true, align="L")
  private String sRecordSeq;

  @DataField(pos=9, length=1, trim=true, defaultValue="2")
  private char sServiceType;

  ...
  ```
- Camel Context

  ```
  <doTry id="_CheckException">
      <camel:convertBodyTo charset="ISO-8859-1"
                      id="_ConvertEncoding" type="java.lang.String"/>
      <camel:unmarshal id="_FileParsing">
         <camel:bindy
                classType="com.ktds.openmzn.dao.KRFixedFormat"
                          locale="korea" type="Fixed"/>
      </camel:unmarshal>
      <doCatch id="_ParsingException">
         <exception>org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodNotFoundException</exception>
         <exception>org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException</exception>
         <convertBodyTo charset="ISO-8859-1"
                      id="_ConvertEncoding" type="java.lang.String"/>
         <toD id="_MoveErrorFile" uri="file:${header.CamelFileParent}/FATAL"/>
      </doCatch>
  </doTry>
  ...
  ```
- Original File

  ```
  H20190312050500GIDRO01LPNPM  
  R0000001269056802668      D201903 ....
  T000000120190312050500000000003091
  ```
- Output File

  ```
  KRFixedFormat [sType=R, sRecordSeq=0000001, sServiceType=2, sChrgId=69056802668, ....
  ```

Comment: I had custom a data format with header, body, and footer. These formats are defined by each class. This case occurs in the case of only one body record with header and footer.